# how to get a value as URL in an entity to a twig

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, twig

I have an Entity called Shop in which it has a property called domainURL. In my twig I did the following:

```
<a href="{{ shop.getSubdomain() }}">
```

However this always appends my root directory to the subdomain resulting in:

```
www.mydomain.com/somesubdomain.test.com
```

How can I just get the URL?

Here's the code for getSubdomain():

```
  /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="subdomain", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $subdomain;


 /**
     * Get subdomain
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSubdomain()
    {
        return $this->subdomain;
    }
```

Comment: show us the code for getSubdomain() ?

Comment: The only possible thing that could be the case given this code is that `$subdomain` actually has the value `www.mydomain.com/somesubdomain.test.com`, maybe take another look at where you set it?

Comment: Just prepend `http://` to `getSubdomain` ?

Comment: @Touki This way the scheme would be hardcoded in there ... not a good idea in my oppinion ;)

Comment: Maybe a scheme-relative url, like "//foo.bar.com"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the browser only **displays** the url prepended with the current domain because the link's href is a relative url (missing the scheme as Touki pointed out) instead of an absolute one.

I would use `{{ app.request.scheme ~ '://' ~ shop.subdomain }}`

info: twig will automatically call the getter, no need to use `shop.getSubdomain()` !